# The location where the operating system should be installed

Tags: hard-drive, memory, installation, operating-systems

Recently i've installed windows 10 operating system on lower capacity **Local Disk C:** (194GB). I've instal some of elementary programs that i need, and now it is more than half full. On other said, my second **Local Disk D:**(758GB) is nearly empty.

- Should have i've installed it on bigger Local Disk D: ?
- Is my PC going to be slower if my Local Disk C: is nearly full, even tho my Local Disk D: is nearly empty??

PS: When i install programs, locaed them on Local Disk D:.

Comment: Windows and its apps are best installed on Drive C and not split over two disks. Numerous people who have tried this come back with something broken. My advice - get a larger main drive. That is what I do.

Comment: More info is needed. Are those partitions located on SSD or HHD? What operating system? etc.

Comment: if both are ssds or hdds of similar speeds, the question could be how to swap the drive letters.

Comment: are these actually 2 different disks?  Or 2 volumes on one disk?

Comment: **2. Answer:** Both local disks are SSD type.  I installed Windows 10 operating system

**3. Answer:** I checked with Defraggler program and they are at similar speeds.

**4. Answer:** The are separated. 
-The main problem with installing programs on Local Disk C: would be that in short period of time there wont be any space left, and Local Disk D: (758GB) would be almost empty. And i assume that would make my PC slower?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of SSDs or HDDs of +/- 800GB so I guess you are using one disk with 2 partitions. Have a look in your Disk managment since that will show you how many disks you actually have.

I recommend you to install the OS on C: and it's own SSD / HDD of 120-256GB. This way you can always easily expand your file storage with a second or third hard disk or replace only the disk of the OS with a bigger one.

If you keep your files and documents all away from the local C: drive then you should have more than enough space. Obviously Programs like Outlook and firefox will use your local appdata folder for storage.